# Why does this site load up in Internet Explorer's Quirks Mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Why does this [site](http://www.posterlion.com/) loads up in Quirks mode? I know i can use X-UA-Compatible but i prefer solving the underlining problem

Comment: Please take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13284083/1169519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how it's defined:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

If you want it to load in standards mode, use the HTML 5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Edit**:

Also, move the initial meta tag down.  This is what I see when I look at your site:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<HTML>
<head>

<title>

20.000+ Cheap Wall Posters and Postcards

</title>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

You have duplicate Content-Type meta tags.  The top one is breaking you into quirks still.  If you remove it altogether, that would be good, and make sure that your charset is accurate (either utf-8 or iso-8859-1).  It should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<HTML>
<head>

<title>

20.000+ Cheap Wall Posters and Postcards

</title>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: from what I can see, the page doesn't even define a doctype.

Comment: @Rob I've changed 

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

to
`<!DOCTYPE html>` But it's still doing it...

Comment: I've edited my response to handle the issue.  I've confirmed that the change I described (plus !DOCTYPE html) will load in standards mode.

Comment: @Rob I'm not pretty good when it comes to these declarations. Could you tell me how it should look like? Maybe like:
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head><body></body></html>


`
?

Comment: Just remove the first line of <meta http-equiv>.  The very first line should be <!DOCTYPE html>.