# IE7 compatability mode. Pages are not displaying in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-7

Some pages of my site are not displaying in IE7 . But it works for IE8 and higher version.
IN devloper option of IE if we set Document mode= Quircks Mode and browser mode = IE7 then it is working.
I have set the HTTP response header in IIS i.e. Name=X-UA-Compatible , Value=IE=EmulateIE7 .

Still it is not working.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: is the problem detected when the pages are running on the intranet? if yes, you should make sure that the browser isn't kicking into compatibility mode due to privacy settings in the intranet zone

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the problem detected when the pages are running on the intranet. How can I make sure the browser is not kicking into compatibility mode due to privacy settings in the intranet zone.
Where should I find this privacy settings?

Comment: [Once again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519)... : )