# IE8 Standards mode for intranet sites

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am developing an intranet site that must be in IE8 standards mode. By default, intranet sites are set to compatibility mode.

Is there any way to set that with a metadata tag?  does not appear to be working.

If the user must change something on their computer, is it possible to set this single intranet site as a site that must be viewed in standards mode?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Do the users run other Intranet sites that must be in compatibility mode?... if not can they turn off that option and thus run yours in Standards Mode?

Comment: I don't know, so I'd rather they not flip that switch for all site.

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an HTTP header (or the equiv Meta tag) to force IE8, IE9, etc. or Edge rendering:

```
<!-- Latest standards -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

or a specific IE version...

```
<!-- Standards (as IE8 handled them) -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```