# IE 8 -> IE 7 Compatibility view. What triggers it?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm wondering what triggers the IE 7 Compatibility View Document Mode in IE 8. I enhanced some website, but I get Stuck in the IE 7 view. I assume it has something to do with Javascript, but what could be the causes? In IE9 + everything renders fine.

Comment: A [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for [`X-UA-Compatible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--  Force IE to use the latest version of its rendering engine -->  
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: This just forces the IE 8 Document Mode. But it seems that someone there is broken.