# !$.support.opacity -- different behaivor on server than localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iis, browser-support

I have a View developed in MVC4 that is using the following client side JavaScript using jquery-1.10.2.min.js lib to see if the user's browser can do certain things or not so we know how to handle them when using http://www.plupload.com/.

I'm running IE 10.0.9200.1671 and when I run this code on my local Windows 7 PC running MS Cassini server via VS, my customRuntime is not 'html4' which is what I expect.  However using other tabs in the same browser and pointing at the same version of this code in our Test and QA Windows 2012 servers running MS IIS8 it shows customRuntime is 'html4'.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var customRuntime = 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,html4';

        //Check to see if browser is IE and version is 8 and less, if so set the runtime to Html4 for plupload.
        if (!$.support.opacity) {
            /* IE 6 to 8 */
            customRuntime = 'html4';
        }

        $('#pickfiles').click(function () {
            $('#help2,#help3,#help4').hide();
            $('#help1').show();
            $('.file.failed').remove();
        });

        uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            chunk_size: '1500kb',
            multipart: true,
            runtimes: customRuntime, //'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
            browse_button: 'pickfiles',
            container: 'ulcontrol',
            max_file_size: '500mb',
            url: 'ProcessUpload',
            //  resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },
            flash_swf_url: '/assets/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url: '/assets/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',
            filters: [
                { title: "Data Files", extensions: "zip,csv" }
            ],
            multiple_queues: false
        });

        uploader.bind('Init', function (up, params) {
            $('#runtime').html(params.runtime + " runtime");
        });

        uploader.init();
        ...
```

Again in the same browser I'm getting "html5 runtime" when pointing to my local server and "html4 runtime" when pointing to Test and QA.  I've looked for missing files/libs on the servers and the code looks fully deployed.  My upload works fine in all environments but some of the HTML5 goodies I expect are not happening and I find it strange that IE 10 is reporting differently from site to site.

My main question is how would this client side code behave different when rendered in the same browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: Compatibility view issue perhaps?  Check if the page triggers the compatibility view when viewed on the test/qa server.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and we had to add the following header to the html document

[IE10 renders in IE7 mode. How to force Standards mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284083/ie10-renders-in-ie7-mode-how-to-force-standards-mode).