# why is IE11 choosing render mode: "IE7 Strict" and how to i make it use current browser?

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, browser

A website that was deployed has crashed, and it is because it is rendering it in "IE7 Strict".  This test was determined by the following code snippet:

```
var vMode = document.documentMode;
var rMode = 'IE5 Quirks Mode';
if(vMode == 8){
  rMode = 'IE8 Standards Mode';
} else if(vMode == 7){
  rMode = 'IE7 Strict Mode';
}
alert('Rendering in: ' + rMode);
```

This is an ASP Web application.

I was thinking that if it were opened with IE11, it would render it in IE11.  It seems that is definitely NOT the case.

How would i resolve this?  Do i have to add something to the config file of my WebApplication, or is an IE module that needs to be removed?  Are there meta tags i need to append to the MasterPage Header?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, IE has it's own tag standards, Murali's answer below is the most appropiate one

Comment: Thanks guys. :)  Yea, IE has always confused me.  My bosses all by default opened it in IE where it worked in Chrome.  I think the best thing is to actually sneak onto their machines and change their default browsers. ;)  heh. 

It seems that Murali might have the correct answer, but i am building and submitting to build queue before i give him the answer points.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519)?

Comment: great alternative to setting the metatag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `X-UA-Compatible to IE=edge` to make use of latest IE version to render

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

check [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e) for more information

Can be configured in web.config for all the pages, also it will make sure that intranet website will render it accordingly. I was facing the problem with internal website, even after adding a META tag. Hence I updated it in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: <Ok, i added that, but i appended to content the additional: ";chrome=1"   as well for Chrome browser etc

Comment: Thanks.  Ill check to confirm, and add a comment if something is not correct.  Then ill give you the thumbs-up-green-checkmark :)

Comment: Is content Case Sensitive?  It seems that the link you gave me etc seems to use: "Edge" and more then a few other examples similarly are UpperCase.  I just wanted to make sure the syntax and documentation was correct for people who visit here in the future.