# site goes on ie7 mode automatically on ie8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a serious issue on a prod site on ie8.

[www.everydayme.ru](http://www.everydayme.ru/)

On ie8, the site goes on ie7 mode and the layout breaks

Can anyone please spot what might be causing this

Thanks

Comment: Please see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519).

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. (Please make sure you have added this mata tag after head tag.)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" > 
.........
.........
</head>
//OR
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" /> 
.........
.........
</head>
//OR
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
.........
.........
</head>
```

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Please check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link for more information.

Comment: You have copied content from 'rewardme.in' ?

Comment: If your site is in asp.net then please also try with the web.config. I have updated my above code snippet. Let me know if anyconcern.

Comment: Thanks..but it did not work :( we just did a roll back on prod