# Website IP address works but not hostname

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Currently I just deployed a website from Debian local server. The Website seems to run very nicely until I reach **internet explorer**. Here is the run down.
I type in the IP address of the server and I get the website with no error.---> 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JOC3.jpg


Now I will try to reach the website via HostName instead of the ip address. But the website will not display correctly.---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/sacrD.jpg

Now this issue only persists in **IE**. Google, firefox, safari... etc will not encounter this problem.

- Other interesting issues:
- on some computers using the servers IPadress or the host name will not display the website correctly.
- Php code does not generate the  the imgs for the gallery.
- style sheets are recognized but not applied to the overall website

Attempt fixes

- lowering security on IE, adding it to website list.
- reloading files on server
- rebooting all machines.

Comment: Is `rotairnet` defined as a host in all your system's `hosts` files, or by a DNS server?

Comment: is IE using some proxy server? http://imgur.com/PtobFl1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your Internet Explorer is using Compatibility View when you view the page using a host name.  It does this if it thinks the page is 'internal' (as in Intranet).

Internet Explorer never uses Compatibility View if you navigate by IP address, because it cannot tell, so it assumes the website is external.

To get your page to be always displayed in standards mode, look at the questions already answered about this: [IE10 renders in IE7 mode. How to force Standards mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284083/ie10-renders-in-ie7-mode-how-to-force-standards-mode)