# forcing jsp's to IE 11 quirks mode without replacing doctypes in each jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, internet-explorer-11, html4

Currently all my jsp's have doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

this forces IE 11 to load in IE 7 document mode.

How to make the application to open in Quirks mode or other standards **without changing each jsp ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1654265

Comment: Hi Andrea. Had gone through this link earlier this is for .net applications that have a web.config i want to know is there any solution to achieve this in struts 2 using web.xml

Comment: I've not understood exactly what you are trying to achieve; but in every case, you'll need to change every JSP; that said, Quirks mode is not a standard, quirks mode is the way a browser try to guess how to treat the content basing on the doctype, or the lack of it, [according to this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types). Finally, IE handles the things in a strange way (that is normal for Microsoft), so if you want IE11 to open (intranet?) sites in IE11 mode, you need to use (carefully) the <meta> or to set the header for X-UA-Compatible