# Internet Explorer doesn't display Websites correctly

Tags: css, windows, internet-explorer

I am jsut working on a new website and I was just doing some cross-browser testing.

Somehow my internet explorer 11 (running on windows 8) doesn't display any website correctly. 
It seems like all background-images won't be displayed. and some other things that are weird.
As far as I found out, it has nothing to do with the compatibility-mode. I already deactivated that.

If you have any idea how to fix that, please tell me!

Thanks in advance, marten!

Comment: It´s better you use normalize. It makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards - http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: @LuisP.A. I did that already. But as I said, its happening on every website! Google as well as facebook, just every single page, that doesn't have anything to do with my styling or what ever

Comment: If this happens for every site, it’s a problem with the browser and hence off-topic her. Might be on-topic at SuperUser, but you surely need to provide much more information to make the question answerable. Think how you would try to help a person who has such a problem. What could you possibly start with?

Comment: Can you post a link to an example or a couple of screenshots showing the good and the bad?  Generally, symptoms like the ones you describe suggest that IE is not up to date, is running a bad add-on, has been forced into compatibility mode, or is being affected by some other environmental factor.  Based on the information available, it's hard to say which.

Comment: @SlimMarten Please check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1169519).