# IE 10 Compatibility Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, internet-explorer-10, meta

I have problem in IE 10 when i open the site in IE it automatically select the Document Mode to IE7 and my site not looking perfectly.

I have do some research and found the to add `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag in header

i have try with following meta tags but not working for me.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,IE=9,IE=8" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE10 renders in IE7 mode. How to force Standards mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284083/ie10-renders-in-ie7-mode-how-to-force-standards-mode)

Comment: @Rob Thanks but i have already read that, i have PHP server. so is there any settings??

Comment: Right-click the rendered page, choose Properties, and then check the value of Zone.  The left side of the value indicates the current zone.  If your zone isn't Internet, then your local settings may be defaulting to compatibility view.   If this is the case, the linked post contains the things you need to check next.  Adding a [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the zone may help.