# What is IE7 mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm developing a web app for a client. It works perfectly on my local machine, and perfectly from my server.

When I provided the code to my client, they deployed it to a QA server, and tested it on a machine (IE10 browser) within their firewall. Sure enough, it doesn't work.

After some research, I found this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955410(v=vs.85).aspx, which says

> If the webpage is retrieved from a site in a domain on the
>   Compatibility View list (and the list is active), IE7 mode is used
>   (see "Understanding the Compatibility View List" at
>   [MSDN-UnderstandingCompViewList]).

I found this helpful SO post about how to turn off Compatibility View: [IE10 renders in IE7 mode. How to force Standards mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284083/ie10-renders-in-ie7-mode-how-to-force-standards-mode)

[image]

However, for my client - the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is both ***checked and disabled*** (i.e., can't be unchecked).

So - my question is, *"What does IE7 mode mean?"*

Does it mean that any function/feature/bit of code that wasn't supported in IE7 won't work (e.g., no SVG?)

Or, something else?

Comment: IE7 mode means what it says on the tin.. any supported features releases above IE7 will not be supported. Only features that are in IE7 are supported.

Comment: It should still be possible to override with X-UA-Compatible, though.

Comment: @JoshStevens - thanks again for your comment. If you make it an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: The surprising thing about this... My corporate client runs a number of web apps that IE considers part of the "intranet zone." So, it automatically renders them in "Compatibility Mode". Further, its IT department has locked down IE - their only supported browser - so that the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is both ***checked and disabled*** (i.e., can't be unchecked). So, effectively, any post-IE7-only feature is broken. Brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IE7` mode means what it says on the tin.. any supported features releases above `IE7` will not be supported. Only features that are in `IE7` are supported.