# IE 10/11 and Edge Shim for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angular, bootstrapping, microsoft-edge

I am getting an error saying the page targets document 5 mode and some features are unavailable when running a Angular2 application. What all shims are needed for IE and Edge for Angular2? I am on IE 11 and also the same page as well does not work with Edge.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-with-ie-11-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not have anything to do with Shims or Angular2. If your page is rendering in Document 5 mode in IE/Edge, there is a possibility that the page is not defining the doctype properly.

To resolve, ensure that you have the following doctype directive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then check your document mode from your browser:

[image]

For more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx

Comment: Ok near. The document mode for IE11 is only when my dev tools are open. When it closes it goes back to IE7. I have IE 11 installed. I have specified the doctype as well but in IE7 it does not seem to work either and angular2 might not work in IE7 as much as I am aware. My question is where do I change the default app mode to IE11 even when the devtools are closed. In IE11 mode I can work with the app.

Comment: Try adding a meta tag: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />. For more information, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284083/ie10-renders-in-ie7-mode-how-to-force-standards-mode

Comment: Ok worked. But it does not work in Edge.It gives a we cant reach this page error in Edge. Seems its not detecting Apache HTTPD Virtual Host. I have Host file already modified and IE works.